# How do I add the mainline kernel PPA?

Tags: kernel, ppa, synaptic

How can I add the mainline kernel ppa to the synaptic software sources?

I have the url:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

but I am missing the *ppa:* line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note:** test/debug kernel versions *higher* than your default kernel, e.g. 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, etc. are only provided via deb files, not via this PPA.

You probably want to [add this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/pre-proposed)-- the only active one the kernel team maintains -- containing the latest *pre-proposed* kernel for each release:

```
ppa:kernel-ppa/pre-proposed
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought they were provided by the ppa above. Yes, I am looking for latest 3.5 kernel.

Comment: @PauloJ.Matos : You can find the necessary deb files for the latest 3.5 [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/).

Comment: @PauloJ.Matos Or you can install 3.5 via PPA http://ubuntuguide.net/install-kernel-3-5-rc-ubuntu-12-04-precise-using-ppa I have to admit that I don't know which is the proper source - this PPA or the debs from izx's comment. I used the PPA, installed only update entries (in update manager) that mentioned kernel, restarted and disabled the PPA via Y PPA Manager to avoid installing anything else from the PPA (xorg edgers).

Comment: @Bucic: the debs are from Ubuntu's kernel team, and your PPA is from a third party (xorg-edgers). I'd trust the former over the latter :)

Comment: @izx It's not like it's some lousy group known to no one, you know ;) But I agree. Upgrading to mainline kernels is not recommended unless you experience problems with you current kernel, but if you're upgrading to mainlin it better be from ubuntu team :)

Comment: This PPA appears to have been abandoned. "Number of packages: 0 source packages (0 bytes) 0 binary packages (0 bytes)". Just the http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ page is left, but I don't want to install unauthenticated packages. It's not HTTPS and there is no GPG signature for the builds. No go for me.

Comment: @gertvdijk This may have changed since you wrote that but the checksum files for the builds on kernel.ubuntu.com are gpg signed. Granted this isn't perfect but if you can hack a SHA256 *and* the SHA1 for a file, you probably have enough compute power to just MITM a SSL connection. It's secure if you're diligent enough to check it.

Comment: @Oli Ah, that's definitely new. The `CHECKSUMS` / `CHECKSUMS.gpg` weren't present before. Great :)

Comment: I suggest using the `ppa:canonical-kernel-team/unstable` PPA - it tracks mainline and may include Ubuntu specific optimizations and back-ports, and it is a PPA that will update your installation automatically. Note the "unstable" tag though - though it is a given that "mainline" is already considered unstable for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge there is no way to add that to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file
There is a script that can get the job done
https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater

Terminal Commands: (edit, more up to date info now in the readme at the above link)

```
cd /tmp
git clone git://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater
bash Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater/install
```

It will check for updates at login+60 seconds, you can check for updates at any time by running `KernelUpdateChecker`
use `-h` or `--help` with that for help output

Answer (score 4):

ukuu is no longer free and open, but mainline is maintained and is free & open.
https://github.com/bkw777/mainline

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Ukuu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu) (which stands for ‘Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility’) This straightforward desktop app help you install a new kernel in Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and other Ubuntu-based distributions, using the “mainline” kernels published by Canonical.

#### Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Then run "ukuu" from your appplication starter and it will show you all stable kernels to choose from. If you want unstable rc-kernels, you can disable the "hide unstable and RC Releases" flag in settings

Answer (score -6):

```
/*tested code already , 
whipped this right up hope it works for you, it downloads the latest kernel from the daily mainline , 
and checks if its on your sys if not installs it 
tested and working :) simply compile as anything .c with your gcc
download at : [here](http://ubuntuone.com/0mLWYLhGPJlHGFXONz6EcO)
*/
//code below ----------------------
// it doesn’t show the imports so put them as comments to the side for who ever just does 
// copy paste 
#include <stdio.h> //stdio.h
#include <stdlib.h> //stdlib.h
#include <string.h> //string.h

void getpage(void)
{
system("mkdir ./kup;cd ./kup;wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/;cat ./index.html|grep -i deb|grep -i linux>>./list;cd ./..");
printf("\n\nwhich archetype would u like to grab \n1: 32 bit\n2: 64bit\n(1/2 1 is default) : ");
char c;
system("uname -i>>./kup/p");
FILE* arch=fopen("./kup/p","r");
c=fgetc(arch);
if(c!='a'){
c=1;}
if(c=='a'){c=2;}
if(c=='2'){
system("cd ./kup;cat ./list|grep -i amd64 >> ./list2;cd ./..");
}
else{
system("cd ./kup;cat ./list|grep -i i386 >> ./list2;cd ./..");
}

system("cd ./kup;cat ./list|grep -i _all >> ./list2;rm -rf ./list;rm -rf ./index.html;cd ./..");

}

int install(void){
printf("\nnow getting ready to check the current kernel install the newest kernel if newer\npress anybtton to continue or q to quit\n");
char c;
c='\n';
if(c=='q'){return 0;}else{
system("dir ./kup>>./kup/test");
char *t=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
t[0]='d';
t[1]='p';
t[2]='k';
t[3]='g';
t[4]=' ';
t[5]='-';
t[6]='l';
t[7]='|';
t[8]='g';
t[9]='r';
t[10]='e';
t[11]='p';
t[12]=' ';
t[13]='-';
t[14]='i';
t[15]=' ';
int tn=16;
FILE* f2 = fopen("./kup/test","r");
char c;
c=fgetc(f2);
while(c!='_'){
t[tn]=c;
tn++;
c=fgetc(f2);
}

t[tn]='>';
tn++;
t[tn]='>';
tn++;
t[tn]='.';
tn++;
t[tn]='/';
tn++;
t[tn]='k';
tn++;
t[tn]='u';
tn++;
t[tn]='p';
tn++;
t[tn]='/';
tn++;
t[tn]='a';
system(t);
FILE *f3 =fopen("./kup/a","r");

char check;
check = fgetc(f3);
printf("\"%c\"",check);
if(check !='i'){
printf("\nthere is a newer version , press enter key to update\n");
system("sudo dpkg -i ./kup/*deb;rm -rf ./kup;sudo update-grub;");
return 0;
}else{printf("\nyour system is up to date\n\n exiting \n");}
system("rm -rf ./kup");
return 0;
}
}

void download(char* url)
{
char *com=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
com[0]='c';
com[1]='d';
com[2]=' ';
com[3]='k';
com[4]='u';
com[5]='p';
com[6]=';';
com[7]='w';
com[8]='g';
com[9]='e';
com[10]='t';
com[11]=' ';
int i=12;
int l =1;
while(l==1)
{
com[i]=url[i-12];
if(com[i]=='b'&&com[i-1]=='e'&&com[i-2]=='d'&&com[i-3]=='.'){
l=0;
}
i++;
}
system("rm -rf ./kup/list2;");
system(com);

}

void getkernel(void){
char links[3][256];
//start writing//
links[0][0]='k';
links[0][1]='e';
links[0][2]='r';
links[0][3]='n';
links[0][4]='e';
links[0][5]='l';
links[0][6]='.';
links[0][7]='u';
links[0][8]='b';
links[0][9]='u';
links[0][10]='n';
links[0][11]='t';
links[0][12]='u';
links[0][13]='.';
links[0][14]='c';
links[0][15]='o';
links[0][16]='m';
links[0][17]='/';
links[0][18]='~';
links[0][19]='k';
links[0][20]='e';
links[0][21]='r';
links[0][22]='n';
links[0][23]='e';
links[0][24]='l';
links[0][25]='-';
links[0][26]='p';
links[0][27]='p';
links[0][28]='a';
links[0][29]='/';
links[0][30]='m';
links[0][31]='a';
links[0][32]='i';
links[0][33]='n';
links[0][34]='l';
links[0][35]='i';
links[0][36]='n';
links[0][37]='e';
links[0][38]='/';
links[0][39]='d';
links[0][40]='a';
links[0][41]='i';
links[0][42]='l';
links[0][43]='y';
links[0][44]='/';
links[0][45]='c';
links[0][46]='u';
links[0][47]='r';
links[0][48]='r';
links[0][49]='e';
links[0][50]='n';
links[0][51]='t';
links[0][52]='/';
//done writing//
char c[5];
int l=1;
FILE* file = fopen("./kup/list2","r");
c[0]=fgetc(file);
while(c[0]!=EOF && l ==1)
{
int u=0;
if(c[0]=='h'){
c[1]=fgetc(file);
if(c[1]=='r'){
c[2]=fgetc(file);
if(c[2]=='e'){
c[3]=fgetc(file);
if(c[3]=='f'){
c[4]=fgetc(file);
c[4]=fgetc(file);
int i=53;
c[4]=fgetc(file);
while(c[4]!='\"'){
links[u][i]=c[4];
i++;
c[4]=fgetc(file);
}

download(links[0]);
u++;
if(u==3){
c[0]=EOF;
l=0;
}
}
}
}
}
c[0]=fgetc(file);
}

}

int main(void)
{
getpage();
getkernel();
install();
}
```

Comment: it checks the current daily build off the ubuntu kernel mainline and updates yours if its not update already cleaned up version , no need for user input , detects the arch of your current kernel (32 bit 64 bit) here http://ubuntuone.com/0mLWYLhGPJlHGFXONz6EcO

Comment: ok posted a link to the one on my ubuntu one and changede the code here and added <br>s

Comment: thanks as u can tell im new to this site , gave an answer and code and adding that now

Comment: update : in the link changed it to use uname -v instead of uname -r to check against the other one on this newest update didnt upgrade the others did so now it will :)) fixed it on that part :) and also if your running ubuntu 13.04 32 bit of it  think it may b compatible get the binary from
http://ubuntuone.com/3cwJte3KtfNNnGcrMcnl6B

Comment: Why on earth is this a C program invoking `system(3)` rather than a shell-script? O_o

Comment: @liyang In order to minimize readability? I was actually wondering the same thing, I was baffled to find this answer .