# Ubuntu 12.10 on Lenovo Z480

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, battery, lenovo

I bought a laptop few days ago, Lenovo Z480 with Windows 8.
After some hours I could finally install dualboot windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10, one thing is that I need to change BIOS setting each time I want to change OS.

But the main issue is that my battery last no more than 1 1/2 hours or 2, and if I watch video less than 1 hour, on the other side using windows 8 the battery last until 4 or 5 hours. Installing Jupiter there's no change, my battery dies so fast.

Would be a linux kernel update in the future to fix this problem? Or I must look for a quick solution? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, if you know what to do, please let me know =)

FEATURES:
Lenovo z480, IdeaPad. 
Processor clock speed: 2.5 GHz, 
Intel Core i5, i5-2450M. 
Internal memory: 4 GB, DDR3-SDRAM,
Hard Disk: 750 GB, 
Graphics NVIDIA GT 630M

Comment: Maybe you can provide some more information abbout the hardware in your laptop. (This is easier for people who want to  answer your question, so they don't have to search for the Lenovo Z480 on the Internet)

Comment: I've already edited the main post, please anyone help me? I'm upgrading ubuntu 13.04 to check if this gets better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you did not install the nvidia driver, the stock Nouveau driver lacks power management, most GPUs will run at full power as a result.
You can get the latest stable gpu drivers from the xswat ppa
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

It is possible a kernel upgrade may fix it see this question:
[How do I add the mainline kernel PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160535/how-do-i-add-the-mainline-kernel-ppa/285613#285613)
I would not hold my breath.

Ubuntu might boot without changing the bios if you use the signed linux image

```
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic linux-signed-image-generic
```

You should be able to find more info using google, that has been asked many time, I never bothered to read it, I don't use windows anymore, if I ever wanted to there is virtualbox
I would rater not have a binary blob from MS in my kernel, which is what the signed kernels have, but you gotta do what you gotta do

Comment: thanks! I've finally fixed it. My battery last 4 or 5 hours now! .
 
It was the NVIDIA driver so just install bumblebee and everything works fine.

About the bios, I prefer to use dual boot, at least until my guarantee expires because it's conditioning me to keep W8, anyway , in the future I'll change it =)