# No sound 12.04 Mac Mini 4,1

Tags: 12.04, sound, hdmi, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini 4,1. I get no sound at all except when I play through the internal speaker. Currently sound is supposed to go through the HDMI cable to the TV. I can see the HDMI output in the sound settings, but I get no love from the speakers. I've double checked the connection as sound works just fine in OSX. This is my first stab at using Ubuntu so ELI5 please.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285624/ubuntu-13-04-not-detect-the-hdmi-sound-output

Comment: @Manuel He uses Ubuntu 12.04, not 13.04 as the user in the other question.

Comment: The headphone jack works just fine. No sound through HDMI. And the power the TV on and off and every combination offers no love.

Comment: I've upgraded to 12.10. And no luck.

Comment: I upgraded to 13 whatever and the sound works now

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacMini as well, same 12.04 haven't solved the issue but have a workaround.

Whenever the monitor/TV is not on during the boot process the sound doesn't work. I normally reboot or put the computer into sleep mode and wake it up again. The sound then works. Mine works with OSX as well but with Ubuntu I need to go through this odd workaround.

Comment: Plot twist: The headphone jack works just fine. No sound through HDMI. And the power the TV on and off and every combination offers no love.

Comment: @Charliticus you know that their are about 3 types of HDMI cables? They have versions like 1.3 1.4 or something, so maybe the cable? It's a slim chance, but I got caught on that once.

Comment: everything works fine in OSX. This is a dual boot installation.