# How do I control the vmem when forking, as I'm getting different results on 10.04 lts and 12.04 lts?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, java

**Expected behavior (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS):**

```
mike@boontoo10:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

mike@boontoo10:~$ java -Xmx512m -Xms512m -jar forker.jar 10000000 20 Xmx512m Xms512m
```

output of "top":

```
1928 mike      20   0  694m  54m 8624 S    6  5.4   0:00.18 java
1933 mike      20   0  694m  54m 8648 S    6  5.4   0:00.18 java
1935 mike      20   0  694m  54m 8648 S    6  5.4   0:00.18 java
1939 mike      20   0  694m  54m 8648 S    5  5.4   0:00.16 java
```

(the java7 output looks like this on 10.04):

```
mike@ubuntu10java7:~$ java -versionjava version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

```
 2106 mike      20   0  734m  57m 9876 S    4  2.8   0:00.25 java               
 2091 mike      20   0  734m  57m 9876 S    3  2.8   0:00.26 java               
 2100 mike      20   0  734m  57m 9876 S    3  2.8   0:00.25 java               
 2112 mike      20   0  734m  57m 9876 S    3  2.8   0:00.24 java               
 2097 mike      20   0  734m  57m 9876 S    3  2.8   0:00.24 java
```

**New behavior (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):**

```
mike@boontoo12:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

mike@boontoo12:~$ java -Xmx512m -Xms512m -jar forker.jar 10000000 20 Xmx512m Xms512m
```

output of "top":

```
20697 mike      20   0 1405m  54m 8488 S    5  1.4   0:00.18 java
20669 mike      20   0 1405m  54m 8492 S    5  1.4   0:00.18 java
20691 mike      20   0 1405m  54m 8492 S    5  1.4   0:00.17 java
20658 mike      20   0 1405m  54m 8492 S    5  1.4   0:00.17 java
```

**Update: New behavior (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS w/ Java 7):**

```
mike@boontoo12java7:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

output of "top":

```
 4166 mike      20   0 1438m  56m 9572 S    7  2.8   0:00.20 java               
 4169 mike      20   0 1438m  56m 9572 S    7  2.8   0:00.20 java               
 4182 mike      20   0 1438m  56m 9572 S    7  2.8   0:00.20 java               
 4076 mike      20   0 1438m  56m 9572 S    6  2.8   0:00.19 java               
 4100 mike      20   0 1438m  56m 9572 S    6  2.8   0:00.19 java
```

ctd...  12.0.4 with OpenJDK 6, similar problem:

```
mike@boontoo12:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

output of "top":

```
 6690 mike      20   0 1500m  55m 8920 S    7  1.4   0:00.22 java               
 6692 mike      20   0 1500m  55m 8920 S    7  1.4   0:00.21 java               
 6697 mike      20   0 1500m  55m 8920 S    7  1.4   0:00.21 java               
 6701 mike      20   0 1500m  51m 8684 S    7  1.3   0:00.21 java               
 6725 mike      20   0 1500m  55m 8920 S    7  1.4   0:00.21 java
```

To preempt, here's the OpenJDK 7 attempt:

```
mike@boontoo12:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

output of "top":

```
 9327 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9296 S    6  1.4   0:00.25 java               
 9331 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9276 S    6  1.4   0:00.25 java               
 9344 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9300 S    6  1.4   0:00.25 java               
 9347 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9300 S    6  1.4   0:00.25 java               
 9323 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9300 S    6  1.4   0:00.25 java               
 9284 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9308 S    5  1.4   0:00.24 java               
 9285 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9300 S    5  1.4   0:00.24 java               
 9336 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9276 S    5  1.4   0:00.23 java               
 9277 mike      20   0 1534m  57m 9300 S    5  1.4   0:00.24 java
```

As you can see, the vmem utilization has doubled.  I'm using the exact same `java/jre binary` (and jdk), the only difference being the version of Ubuntu.

I'm hoping to get this program back to ~694m of vmem used.  How do I do that?  What do I even search for?

Please don't suggest that I structure my program differently.  This is the smallest toy-example I could write to reproduce a gigantic problem reflected in some Apache Software, but this feels like a kernel/libs problem to me.

Here's the code to duplicate, and the link where all this is summarized in a gist: https://gist.github.com/michael-trelinski

Code:

```
package com.satoricode.forker;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ForkIt {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.print("Filling up some memory... ");
        int[] arr = fillItUp(arraySize);
        System.out.println("" + arr.length + " done.");
        if (args.length == 1) {
            System.out.println("I'm the fork!");
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } else {
            // I'm the master
            int numForks = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            String stackCommand = args[2];
            String stackInitCommand = args[3];
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numForks);

            System.out.println("Launching " + numForks + " forks with array size " + arraySize + " with -" + stackCommand + " -" + stackInitCommand);
            for(int I = 0; I < numForks; I++)
                pool.execute(new ForkRunner(arraySize, stackCommand, stackInitCommand));

            pool.shutdown();
            System.out.print("Waiting for pool to finish");
            while(!pool.isTerminated()) {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                System.out.print(".");              
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("done\n");           
        }
    }

    private static int[] fillItUp(int total) {
        int[] arr = new int[total];
        for (int I = 0; I < total; I++)
            arr[I] = I;
        return arr;
    }

}


package com.satoricode.forker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class ForkRunner implements Runnable {

  private String stackCommand;
    private int arraySize;
    private String stackInitCommand;

    public ForkRunner(int arraySize, String stackCommand, String stackInitCommand) {
        this.arraySize = arraySize;
        this.stackCommand = stackCommand;
        this.stackInitCommand = stackInitCommand;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String command = "java -" + stackCommand + " -" + stackInitCommand + " -jar forker.jar " + arraySize;
            System.out.println("executing: " + command);
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            InputStream input = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStream error = proc.getErrorStream();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int c = -1;
            while ((c = input.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) c);
            }
            while ((c = error.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) c);
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: mm... Do you get the same results in Java7? JDK6 or 7?

Comment: @Braiam I will try that out, but I suspect since I used the same java binary to install on both Ubuntu versions, that it's something os/kernel-based.

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't be using Java6 on recent versions, is quite buggy and unmaintained so maybe is just the combination recent kernel + old java.

Comment: @Braiam I just did a vanilla 12.04 server install and did a sun java jre 1.7 install.  Nearly identical problem.  Updated original post.  Will try out java 7 on 10.04 and see if I get a similar result from java 6 on 10.4...

Comment: @Braiam I just did a vanilla 10.04 server install and did a sun java jre 1.7 install.  Nearly identical functionality.  I really do believe this has eliminated java 6 / 7 as a suspect and points to something kernel based/fork-related in 10.04 versus 12.04.

Comment: Ok, then is a regression in the Kernel. Read [Instructions on filing a bug report](http://$SITEURL$/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), and report your bug.

Comment: At last long shot, could you try 13.04 or 13.10 saucy. When you report the bug, they will most likely ask you to do this. http://askubuntu.com/q/160535/169736

Comment: FWIW, I tested this on the lowest kernel available on 12.04, same problem.  I've also tested it with the newest kernel for 12.04, same thing.

Comment: I have also tested it on 13.04 with the vanilla kernel, and the newest kernel.  Same problem.

Comment: Forgot to ask you the most important thing... are you using Sun's Java?

Comment: Yes, Sun's Java.  I pasted the "java -version" on all of the tests I illustrated above.  It's all Sun/Oracle Java.

Comment: ARG! [Quote](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11306391#11306391): *"If it is, it's a bug I'm not aware of, however, it's possible they're using Sun Java, not OpenJDK, and if they're using Oracle's java (sun java) that's not anything in the repos so it's not only a bug it's offtopic because E: Not In Ubuntu."* Sorry Mike, but IMHO you will always have problems with Sun's Java in recent version. Try OpenJDK or Java 7 from the repositories, there should be no problem there.

Comment: OpenJDK isn't (very) condoned for running Apache's Hadoop, but like I keep saying, I really believe this is a problem with fork() at the kernel/source-level.  I will test this out with OpenJDK 6 and 7, and post the results later.  I anticipate that they will be the same.

Comment: I have tried OpenJDK 6 and 7, and still the same problem.  I am willing to write the program to demonstrate/prove this in C if it will pacify you guys... but I have tried everything you have suggested.  I really believe based on how the diagnostic process works, that we have eliminated the JRE/JDK as the source of the problem.  I really believe this comes down to the linux JDK calling out to fork()/vfork()/exec().  I'll read the java source code to ascertain which call it is getting and make the patch myself.

Comment: "if it will pacify you guys" no way, I'm not mad, nor even bothered. I was just trying to dissect where the problem was before you reported the bug, so the report didn't needed any information from you.