# Ubuntu 14.04 problem with usb 3.0

Tags: 14.04, usb, external-hdd

I've some problem with my usb 3.0 and an external HD.
Both works fine because if I plug my external HD to the usb 2.0 all works ok, and If I plug a memory stick to the usb 3.0 all works ok.

> USB 3.0 + HD = BAD
>
> USB 2.0 + HD = OK
>
> USB 3.0 + MEMORY STICK = OK
>
> USB 2.0 + MEMORY STICK = OK

...do you have some ideas?

Comment: Your hard drive isn't compatible with the USB 3 chipset of your motherboard or the USB 3 driver in Linux. For some potential solutions see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457901/usb-2-0-device-scanner-does-not-work-with-xhci-hcd-on-usb-3-0-system#463497).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be with the compatibility with the chip of the box of the external HD and ubuntu, because with other external HD (such as samsung 2TB and WD 1TB) everything goes well.

Nevertheless that external HD works well with other notebook which run windows.