# Problem with CanoScan Lide 20 not working in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, scanner, canon, sane

I have a few weeks a new desktop PCs with Intel i5 processor with 8.1 installed dual boot windows and ubuntu 14:10 64 bits.
My old pc and also in my notebook with ubuntu 14.04 were connected to the scanner Canon CanoScan LiDE 20 via usb and managed to acquire documents.
Instead the new PC can not get it.
If I type lsusb from terminal I get:

```
 Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04a9:220d Canon, Inc. CanoScan N670U/N676U/LiDE 20
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c03e Logitech, Inc. Premium Optical Wheel Mouse (M-BT58)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:6340 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I installed the software, and pay for it $ 29.90,  vuescan, and this works perfectly. Simple scan, xsane, skanlite, they can not find the scanner, it seems to be a problem for sane.

Comment: For my LiDe 25 simple-scan even crashes with a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: See [USB 2.0 device (scanner) does not work with xhci_hcd on USB 3.0 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457901/usb-2-0-device-scanner-does-not-work-with-xhci-hcd-on-usb-3-0-system)

Answer (score 0):

Please view this [online tutorial](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/02/how-to-get-an-canon-canoscan-lide-100-scanner-to-work-in-ubuntu-11-10linux-mint-12.html) and/or try a different usb cable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue in the scanning (SANE) backend when using systems with USB3 support: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1250196

Answer (score 0):

Changing the LIDE20 scanner from a USB 3.0 to a USB 2.0 port was the solution for my Xsane installation. It would see the scanner on the USB3 port but coul'd not activate the scanner itself with communication errors. This worked for me on a ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS machine. Thanks for the info!