# Trouble accessing harddrive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, data-recovery

Hoping someone can help me out here, im quite new so please excuse any false assumptions.

I recently had a relatives mac boot drive fail(seems mechanically fine, but wont appear in OSX or windows). I decided to try plugging it into one of my macs thats dual booted with ubuntu.

The drive does not appear as a drive normally would, however I can see the computer recognize it when plugged in(so im assuming ill have to force mount it?).

The drive appears in lsusb and dmesg(see below for output), however it doesn't show up in fdisk, dev/ or lsscsi so i dont have a location to force mount from(if that makes sense).

Here is the dmesg output:

```
phillip@phillip-MacBook:~$ dmesg | tail
[  831.605083] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[  831.605533] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  831.615541] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  862.869622] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  998.212232] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  998.348140] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0621
[  998.348152] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[  998.348159] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1
[  998.566959] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  998.567521] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
```

Judging by the output of successful mounts ive seen, should it not be handing that off to another process?

*Edit: Im just realizing now that it says using "ehci-pci"........im pretty sure one of the earlier times I was toying with this is it was "uhci".....does that make sense?*

Here is the lsusb output:(drive is device 6 in list)

```
phillip@phillip-MacBook:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:8300 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight (no firmware loaded)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 05ac:0229 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (MacBook Pro) (ANSI)
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1f75:0621 Innostor Technology Corporation 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05ac:8205 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth HCI
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Here is sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="70D6-1701" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="13bc40a0-e29b-33fd-adb4-c04e173b2ff2" LABEL="Macintosh HD" TYPE="hfsplus" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="38a678ae-0c9b-4c1c-a333-f5c9551eb13f" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="6b0d0a7f-776e-4534-b618-a21b0aa2ce86" TYPE="swap"
```

Output of lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/002/005

```
phillip@phillip-MacBook:~$ lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/002/005
Device: ID 1f75:0621 Innostor Technology Corporation 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1f75 Innostor Technology Corporation
  idProduct          0x0621 
  bcdDevice            0.36
  iManufacturer           4 
  iProduct                5 
  iSerial                 6 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

Anybody have any suggestions on where to go next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post the output of the command: `sudo blkid`

Comment: @mchid as requested

phillip@phillip-MacBook:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for phillip: 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="70D6-1701" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="13bc40a0-e29b-33fd-adb4-c04e173b2ff2" LABEL="Macintosh HD" TYPE="hfsplus" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="38a678ae-0c9b-4c1c-a333-f5c9551eb13f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="6b0d0a7f-776e-4534-b618-a21b0aa2ce86" TYPE="swap"

Comment: related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1332722 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457901/usb-2-0-device-scanner-does-not-work-with-xhci-hcd-on-usb-3-0-system

Answer (score 0):

If this was from OSX you will probably have to add some packages for hfs type filesystem support. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hfsutils hfsplus hfsprogs
```

Comment: I wondered about that, will do now and post results.

Comment: don't forget to click the icon to the left if this answers your question and please post any errors, thanks!

Comment: Doesnt seem to have changed anything, as im running ubuntu dual booted on a mac, Im wondering if some how support was already there.

Comment: Does it matter that the enclosure the drive is in is USB3.0?

Comment: I don't think it should matter. Also, try unplugging it and plugging it back in.

Comment: Ive tried a bunch of times, would it be worth it to unplug the enclosure adapter from the drive and plug it in with no drive attached?(Thinking that perhaps its not detecting a drive at all and just the adapters hardware)

Comment: @piller97 actually according to here:https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1332722 it probably is a usb3.0 issue, try a 2.0 USB port if you have one.

Comment: Ive only got a 3.0 cord for the drive enclosure, I could install the drive in a mac and access via target disk. but id have to use firewire

Comment: how would i do that(sorry, quite new here)

Comment: @piller97 It looks like you can use one of those cheap short USB2.0 extension cables to force USB2.0 on the device see similar issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/457901/usb-2-0-device-scanner-does-not-work-with-xhci-hcd-on-usb-3-0-system

Comment: @piller97 also, the 3.0 module is built into the kernel and will not remove when issuing the command so I don't think it can be disabled through the command line but definitely check out the short usb2.0 extension option as that did come to mind and it looks like it works for other devices.

Comment: Ill try to get my hands on a 2.0 cable tomorrow. Dont know if its useful but ive added some more specific info about the drive to the question

Comment: Just realized that USB3.0 shouldn't be an issue, I'm so used to my newer machine that i didn't even remember the mac running linux doesn't even have 3.0 ports, Id say this is causing the error, but I have a dedicated USB3.0 external drive that mounts fine on the system

Comment: @piller97 I don't know much about Macs but on any pc I would just remove the internal drive and replace it with the one you are having trouble with and boot up using a USB pen drive with a live session of ubuntu or just hook it up to one of the extra sata ports on a tower. Of course you'll probably have to install the hfs support after you boot up.