# laptop hangs and dies with following crash log.

Tags: networking, kernel, kubuntu, xhci-hcd

```
May 11 10:48:50 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [   87.533282] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 11 10:48:50 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [   87.533284] usb 3-1: Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
     ..............
     ...............

May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017497] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8801fc0896c0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017504] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8801fc089740
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017507] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8801fc089700
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017510] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3d40
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017512] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3d00
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017515] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3ac0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017517] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3a80
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017520] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3fc0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017522] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3f80
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017525] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3000
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.017527] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800360e3040
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018149] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018163] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 2437 at /home/apw/COD/linux/drivers/usb/host/xhci-ring.c:599 xhci_find_new_dequeue_state+0x15d/0x290()
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018165] Modules linked in: zte_ev usbserial usb_storage rfcomm bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm arc4 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath9k crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_rawmidi ath9k_common ghash_clmulni_intel ath9k_hw ath aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq microcode joydev ath3k btusb serio_raw bluetooth snd_seq_device snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 snd memstick lpc_ich 6lowpan_iphc soundcore sony_laptop parport_pc mei_me ppdev mei mac_hid lp parport rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse drm r8169 ahci rtsx_pci mii wmi video
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018232] CPU: 3 PID: 2437 Comm: usb-storage Not tainted 3.14.3-031403-generic #201405061153
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018234] Hardware name: Sony Corporation SVT13135CXS/VAIO, BIOS R1100D4 11/14/2012
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018236]  0000000000000257 ffff8801fc29ba78 ffffffff817633e5 0000000000000007
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018241]  0000000000000000 ffff8801fc29bab8 ffffffff8106ac9c ffffffff8159bc20
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018244]  ffff8800a32a2000 ffff8801fc29bb40 ffff88022ebf8b80 00000001fc274800
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018248] Call Trace:
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018255]  [<ffffffff817633e5>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018261]  [<ffffffff8106ac9c>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8c/0xc0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018265]  [<ffffffff8159bc20>] ? trace_xhci_dbg_quirks+0x70/0x70
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018269]  [<ffffffff8106acea>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018274]  [<ffffffff815a9c2d>] xhci_find_new_dequeue_state+0x15d/0x290
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018277]  [<ffffffff815a0398>] xhci_cleanup_stalled_ring+0x78/0x100
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018281]  [<ffffffff815a0556>] xhci_endpoint_reset+0x136/0x190
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018287]  [<ffffffff8156df85>] usb_hcd_reset_endpoint+0x25/0x70
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018290]  [<ffffffff815711e8>] usb_enable_endpoint+0xa8/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018293]  [<ffffffff81571232>] usb_enable_interface+0x42/0x60
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018297]  [<ffffffff81567a40>] usb_reset_and_verify_device+0x210/0x4a0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018303]  [<ffffffff814b1c74>] ? device_release_driver+0x34/0x40
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018306]  [<ffffffff81567dc0>] usb_reset_device+0xf0/0x1d0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018313]  [<ffffffffa06b8f89>] usb_stor_port_reset+0x69/0x70 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018317]  [<ffffffffa06b9026>] usb_stor_invoke_transport+0x96/0x570 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018322]  [<ffffffffa06b7e5e>] usb_stor_transparent_scsi_command+0xe/0x10 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018327]  [<ffffffffa06ba68a>] usb_stor_control_thread+0x1ba/0x310 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018332]  [<ffffffffa06ba4d0>] ? fill_inquiry_response+0x20/0x20 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018336]  [<ffffffff8108ffa9>] kthread+0xc9/0xe0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018339]  [<ffffffff8108fee0>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0xb0/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018342]  [<ffffffff81779d7c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018345]  [<ffffffff8108fee0>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0xb0/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018347] ---[ end trace 60d1ae0297f61c92 ]---
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018357] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000010
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018402] IP: [<ffffffff815a9dcc>] xhci_queue_new_dequeue_state+0x6c/0xe0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018440] PGD 0 
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018453] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018473] Modules linked in: zte_ev usbserial usb_storage rfcomm bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm arc4 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath9k crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_rawmidi ath9k_common ghash_clmulni_intel ath9k_hw ath aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq microcode joydev ath3k btusb serio_raw bluetooth snd_seq_device snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 snd memstick lpc_ich 6lowpan_iphc soundcore sony_laptop parport_pc mei_me ppdev mei mac_hid lp parport rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse drm r8169 ahci rtsx_pci mii wmi video
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018882] CPU: 3 PID: 2437 Comm: usb-storage Tainted: G        W    3.14.3-031403-generic #201405061153
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018929] Hardware name: Sony Corporation SVT13135CXS/VAIO, BIOS R1100D4 11/14/2012
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.018968] task: ffff8800a37f98f0 ti: ffff8801fc29a000 task.ti: ffff8801fc29a000
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019005] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff815a9dcc>]  [<ffffffff815a9dcc>] xhci_queue_new_dequeue_state+0x6c/0xe0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019054] RSP: 0018:ffff8801fc29bac8  EFLAGS: 00010046
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019081] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8801fc29bb40 RCX: 0000000000000240
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019116] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff8801fc102900 RDI: 0000000000000000
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019151] RBP: ffff8801fc29bb28 R08: ffff8801fc29bb40 R09: ffff8801fc102900
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019186] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 00000000000003b3 R12: ffff8800a32a2000
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019221] R13: ffff88009c1acfe8 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000012
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019257] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88024f2c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019297] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019325] CR2: 0000000000000010 CR3: 0000000001c0d000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019361] Stack:
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019371]  ffff8801fc29bb38 ffff8801fc29bae8 ffffffff81addf5a ffff8801fc102900
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019412]  ffff880100000002 00000000fc274801 ffff8800a32a2000 ffff88009c1acfe8
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019451]  ffff8800a32a2000 ffff8800a4275000 0000000000000012 ffff8800a32a2048
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019492] Call Trace:
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019508]  [<ffffffff815a0419>] xhci_cleanup_stalled_ring+0xf9/0x100
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019542]  [<ffffffff815a0556>] xhci_endpoint_reset+0x136/0x190
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019575]  [<ffffffff8156df85>] usb_hcd_reset_endpoint+0x25/0x70
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019607]  [<ffffffff815711e8>] usb_enable_endpoint+0xa8/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019638]  [<ffffffff81571232>] usb_enable_interface+0x42/0x60
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019670]  [<ffffffff81567a40>] usb_reset_and_verify_device+0x210/0x4a0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019705]  [<ffffffff814b1c74>] ? device_release_driver+0x34/0x40
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019738]  [<ffffffff81567dc0>] usb_reset_device+0xf0/0x1d0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019771]  [<ffffffffa06b8f89>] usb_stor_port_reset+0x69/0x70 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019808]  [<ffffffffa06b9026>] usb_stor_invoke_transport+0x96/0x570 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019849]  [<ffffffffa06b7e5e>] usb_stor_transparent_scsi_command+0xe/0x10 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019892]  [<ffffffffa06ba68a>] usb_stor_control_thread+0x1ba/0x310 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019933]  [<ffffffffa06ba4d0>] ? fill_inquiry_response+0x20/0x20 [usb_storage]
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019972]  [<ffffffff8108ffa9>] kthread+0xc9/0xe0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.019999]  [<ffffffff8108fee0>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0xb0/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.020031]  [<ffffffff81779d7c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.020059]  [<ffffffff8108fee0>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0xb0/0xb0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.020089] Code: 03 84 d7 10 01 00 00 4d 8b 48 08 4c 89 c3 49 89 fc 44 89 55 c0 4c 89 f7 4c 89 ce 4c 8d 68 28 4c 89 4d b8 e8 77 ec ff ff 8b 53 10 <4d> 8b 46 10 4c 89 f1 4c 8b 4d b8 48 89 04 24 4c 89 e7 48 c7 c6 
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.020250] RIP  [<ffffffff815a9dcc>] xhci_queue_new_dequeue_state+0x6c/0xe0
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.020288]  RSP <ffff8801fc29bac8>
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.021923] CR2: 0000000000000010
May 11 10:49:12 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  109.032004] ---[ end trace 60d1ae0297f61c93 ]---
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852054] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852066] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 0 at /home/apw/COD/linux/kernel/watchdog.c:245 watchdog_overflow_callback+0x9a/0xc0()
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852068] Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 3
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852069] Modules linked in: zte_ev usbserial usb_storage rfcomm bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm arc4 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath9k crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_rawmidi ath9k_common ghash_clmulni_intel ath9k_hw ath aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq microcode joydev ath3k btusb serio_raw bluetooth snd_seq_device snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 snd memstick lpc_ich 6lowpan_iphc soundcore sony_laptop parport_pc mei_me ppdev mei mac_hid lp parport rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse drm r8169 ahci rtsx_pci mii wmi video
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852133] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Tainted: G      D W    3.14.3-031403-generic #201405061153
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852135] Hardware name: Sony Corporation SVT13135CXS/VAIO, BIOS R1100D4 11/14/2012
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852137]  00000000000000f5 ffff88024f2c7ba8 ffffffff817633e5 0000000000000007
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852141]  ffff88024f2c7bf8 ffff88024f2c7be8 ffffffff8106ac9c 0000000000000000
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852145]  ffff880243b78000 0000000000000000 ffff88024f2c7d18 0000000000000000
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852149] Call Trace:
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852151]  <NMI>  [<ffffffff817633e5>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852162]  [<ffffffff8106ac9c>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8c/0xc0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852166]  [<ffffffff8106ad86>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x50
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852170]  [<ffffffff8111968a>] watchdog_overflow_callback+0x9a/0xc0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852175]  [<ffffffff81156078>] __perf_event_overflow+0x98/0x230
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852180]  [<ffffffff8102c878>] ? x86_perf_event_set_period+0xd8/0x150
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852184]  [<ffffffff81156984>] perf_event_overflow+0x14/0x20
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852188]  [<ffffffff81034291>] intel_pmu_handle_irq+0x1c1/0x2b0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852192]  [<ffffffff81772744>] perf_event_nmi_handler+0x34/0x60
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852196]  [<ffffffff81771e9a>] nmi_handle.isra.3+0x8a/0x1a0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852199]  [<ffffffff817727c0>] ? perf_ibs_nmi_handler+0x50/0x50
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852202]  [<ffffffff81772098>] default_do_nmi+0x58/0x240
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852205]  [<ffffffff81772310>] do_nmi+0x90/0xd0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852208]  [<ffffffff817712b1>] end_repeat_nmi+0x1e/0x2e
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852213]  [<ffffffff81770770>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0x30/0x50
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852217]  [<ffffffff81770770>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0x30/0x50
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852221]  [<ffffffff81770770>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0x30/0x50
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852222]  <<EOE>>  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff815accc3>] xhci_irq+0x33/0x1f0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852229]  [<ffffffff815ace91>] xhci_msi_irq+0x11/0x20
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852233]  [<ffffffff810ca27d>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x5d/0x210
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852237]  [<ffffffff810ca478>] handle_irq_event+0x48/0x70
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852241]  [<ffffffff810cce77>] handle_edge_irq+0x77/0x110
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852246]  [<ffffffff810181e2>] handle_irq+0x22/0x40
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852250]  [<ffffffff8177c15e>] do_IRQ+0x5e/0x110
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852254]  [<ffffffff81770c2d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852256]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff81603001>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x61/0xe0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852263]  [<ffffffff81602ff7>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x57/0xe0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852267]  [<ffffffff81603140>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xc0/0x210
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852271]  [<ffffffff8101fede>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852275]  [<ffffffff810c9698>] cpu_idle_loop+0x98/0x260
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852279]  [<ffffffff810df2a2>] ? clockevents_register_device+0xe2/0x140
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852283]  [<ffffffff810c98cb>] cpu_startup_entry+0x6b/0x70
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852287]  [<ffffffff81046798>] start_secondary+0xc8/0xd0
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  265.852289] ---[ end trace 60d1ae0297f61c94 ]---
May 11 10:52:56 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  333.241639] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933756] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [mount.ntfs:2600]
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933761] Modules linked in: zte_ev usbserial usb_storage rfcomm bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm arc4 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath9k crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_rawmidi ath9k_common ghash_clmulni_intel ath9k_hw ath aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq microcode joydev ath3k btusb serio_raw bluetooth snd_seq_device snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 snd memstick lpc_ich 6lowpan_iphc soundcore sony_laptop parport_pc mei_me ppdev mei mac_hid lp parport rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse drm r8169 ahci rtsx_pci mii wmi video
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933846] CPU: 2 PID: 2600 Comm: mount.ntfs Tainted: G      D W    3.14.3-031403-generic #201405061153
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933849] Hardware name: Sony Corporation SVT13135CXS/VAIO, BIOS R1100D4 11/14/2012
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933853] task: ffff8801e98ccad0 ti: ffff88007a76c000 task.ti: ffff88007a76c000
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933856] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810e7856>]  [<ffffffff810e7856>] smp_call_function_many+0x206/0x260
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933864] RSP: 0018:ffff88007a76dd28  EFLAGS: 00000202
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933867] RAX: 0000000000000003 RBX: ffff8802433c9f88 RCX: ffff88024f2d7ed8
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933870] RDX: 0000000000000003 RSI: 0000000000000100 RDI: 0000000000000100
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933872] RBP: ffff88007a76dd78 R08: ffff88024f295008 R09: 0000000000000000
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933875] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000297
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933878] R13: ffff88007a76dcd8 R14: 0000000000000101 R15: ffff88007a76dd50
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933881] FS:  00007f6456deb740(0000) GS:ffff88024f280000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933884] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933887] CR2: 00007f645655f380 CR3: 000000007a4cc000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933890] Stack:
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933892]  ffff8802433c9d40 01ff8802433c9f80 0000000000000002 0000000000014fc0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933898]  0000000000000000 ffffffff812073e0 0000000000000000 ffff88007a76ddc8
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933904]  0000000000000002 ffffffff81d0c7c0 ffff88007a76dda8 ffffffff810e79a7
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933910] Call Trace:
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933919]  [<ffffffff812073e0>] ? buffer_cpu_notify+0xa0/0xa0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933924]  [<ffffffff810e79a7>] on_each_cpu_mask+0x37/0x80
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933929]  [<ffffffff81205d10>] ? mark_buffer_async_write+0x20/0x20
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933934]  [<ffffffff812073e0>] ? buffer_cpu_notify+0xa0/0xa0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933938]  [<ffffffff810e7aa3>] on_each_cpu_cond+0xb3/0xe0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933944]  [<ffffffff812063b9>] invalidate_bh_lrus+0x29/0x30
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933948]  [<ffffffff8120e292>] kill_bdev+0x22/0x40
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933953]  [<ffffffff8120f725>] set_blocksize+0xa5/0xc0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933958]  [<ffffffff8135c4c2>] blkdev_ioctl+0x582/0x810
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933963]  [<ffffffff8120d4b0>] block_ioctl+0x40/0x50
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933970]  [<ffffffff811e6765>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x75/0x2c0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933975]  [<ffffffff810241b5>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x165/0x280
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933980]  [<ffffffff810243ad>] ? syscall_trace_leave+0xdd/0x150
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933985]  [<ffffffff811e6a41>] SyS_ioctl+0x91/0xb0
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933990]  [<ffffffff8177a03f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
May 11 10:57:19 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  595.933993] Code: 48 63 d0 e8 bd 4e 2a 00 3b 05 97 61 c2 00 0f 8d 85 fe ff ff 48 63 d0 49 8b 0c 24 48 03 0c d5 80 bb d0 81 f6 41 20 01 74 cc f3 90 <f6> 41 20 01 74 c4 eb f6 0f b6 4d bf 4c 89 f2 4c 89 ee 89 df e8 
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  610.921379] perf samples too long (2505 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924855] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [mount.ntfs:2600]
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924859] Modules linked in: zte_ev usbserial usb_storage rfcomm bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm arc4 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event ath9k crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_rawmidi ath9k_common ghash_clmulni_intel ath9k_hw ath aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq microcode joydev ath3k btusb serio_raw bluetooth snd_seq_device snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 snd memstick lpc_ich 6lowpan_iphc soundcore sony_laptop parport_pc mei_me ppdev mei mac_hid lp parport rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse drm r8169 ahci rtsx_pci mii wmi video
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924919] CPU: 2 PID: 2600 Comm: mount.ntfs Tainted: G      D W    3.14.3-031403-generic #201405061153
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924921] Hardware name: Sony Corporation SVT13135CXS/VAIO, BIOS R1100D4 11/14/2012
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924923] task: ffff8801e98ccad0 ti: ffff88007a76c000 task.ti: ffff88007a76c000
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924925] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810e785a>]  [<ffffffff810e785a>] smp_call_function_many+0x20a/0x260
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924931] RSP: 0018:ffff88007a76dd28  EFLAGS: 00000202
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924933] RAX: 0000000000000003 RBX: ffff8802433c9f88 RCX: ffff88024f2d7ed8
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924935] RDX: 0000000000000003 RSI: 0000000000000100 RDI: 0000000000000100
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924937] RBP: ffff88007a76dd78 R08: ffff88024f295008 R09: 0000000000000000
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924939] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000297
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924941] R13: ffff88007a76dcd8 R14: 0000000000000101 R15: ffff88007a76dd50
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924943] FS:  00007f6456deb740(0000) GS:ffff88024f280000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924945] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924947] CR2: 00007f645655f380 CR3: 000000007a4cc000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924949] Stack:
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924950]  ffff8802433c9d40 01ff8802433c9f80 0000000000000002 0000000000014fc0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924954]  0000000000000000 ffffffff812073e0 0000000000000000 ffff88007a76ddc8
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924958]  0000000000000002 ffffffff81d0c7c0 ffff88007a76dda8 ffffffff810e79a7
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924962] Call Trace:
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924968]  [<ffffffff812073e0>] ? buffer_cpu_notify+0xa0/0xa0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924972]  [<ffffffff810e79a7>] on_each_cpu_mask+0x37/0x80
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924976]  [<ffffffff81205d10>] ? mark_buffer_async_write+0x20/0x20
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924980]  [<ffffffff812073e0>] ? buffer_cpu_notify+0xa0/0xa0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924983]  [<ffffffff810e7aa3>] on_each_cpu_cond+0xb3/0xe0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924987]  [<ffffffff812063b9>] invalidate_bh_lrus+0x29/0x30
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924990]  [<ffffffff8120e292>] kill_bdev+0x22/0x40
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924994]  [<ffffffff8120f725>] set_blocksize+0xa5/0xc0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.924998]  [<ffffffff8135c4c2>] blkdev_ioctl+0x582/0x810
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.925001]  [<ffffffff8120d4b0>] block_ioctl+0x40/0x50
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.925006]  [<ffffffff811e6765>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x75/0x2c0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.925010]  [<ffffffff810241b5>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x165/0x280
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.925013]  [<ffffffff810243ad>] ? syscall_trace_leave+0xdd/0x150
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.925016]  [<ffffffff811e6a41>] SyS_ioctl+0x91/0xb0
May 11 10:57:47 gyanu-SVT13135CXS kernel: [  623.925020]  [<ffffffff8177a03f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
```

Comment: More info needed. What were you doing, error occurred at what time (boot, when plugging a device etc.)

Comment: yes it happens frequently when i plug my cdma evdo internet device. This doesnot happens with previous linux kernel.first i see the crash log from dmesg command. if i unplug device i cannot do any thing. Basically system won't be usable when that log appears.

Comment: Which kernel are you using? find it with `uname -a` command

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.3-utopic/ i was  using this.

Comment: what i mostly noticed is usb networking device and system may be working normaly but when it goes to sleep  and awaken. This crash is likely to happen.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hit a bug in the Linux kernel - [kernel.org bug #75521](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75521). Make sure you are running the latest kernel packages. You could also try to upgrade to the mainline kernel where the bug might be fixed already (see [How do I add the mainline kernel PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160535/how-do-i-add-the-mainline-kernel-ppa)), or downgrade to the previous kernel where this was working for you.

edit: you just confirmed you are using the mainline PPA, in which case purging the PPA and reverting back to the default kernel might fix the issue.

Comment: i have main Linux kernel gyanu-SVT13135CXS 3.13.0-26-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 7 23:31:02 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  also but sometime touchpad doesn't work consistently.So i was having two kernels.

Comment: If you are feeling particular adventurous, you could install the latest tip kernel, verify that the bug exists there, and if so, report it on the linux kernel mailing list.