# I want to use the Linux 4.7 Kernel in 16.04.01. Where can I find the repo?

Tags: 16.04, kernel

Hello I am using `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` and have also used `Arch Linux` and `Kali Linux` both of which were running `Linux 4.7 Kernel` and I have to admit that my laptop boots faster in the **4.7 Kernel** and also it heats up less.

So where can  find such a **`ppa for Ubuntu 16.04.1`**??

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/160535/how-do-i-add-the-mainline-kernel-ppa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PPA. Those need to be downloaded directly from: [kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/). Mind that these DEBs are NOT supported by Ubuntu (the Ubuntu kernel team changes these to fit Ubuntu).

Download the DEBs appropriate to your system and install with ...

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

---

> I have to admit that my laptop boots faster in the 4.7 Kernel and also it heats up less

It is not guaranteed that in Ubuntu these 2 issues are fixed. I myself would stick to the other 2 OS's for now.